# ros indigo on a raspberry pi won't start because of missing roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros Indigo on a brand new raspbian wheezy follwing the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) from the wiki.

I get this

```
pi@RPiMower /opt/ros/indigo/bin $ sudo ./roscore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./roscore", line 62, in <module>
    import roslaunch
ImportError: No module named roslaunch
```

but when i start python i can Import roslaunch without Problems.

```
pi@RPiMower /opt/ros/indigo/bin $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import roslaunch
>>>
```

What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216644/ros-indigo-on-a-raspberry-pi-won%27t-start-because-of-missing-roslaunch/) by [bgewehr](https://answers.ros.org/users/23670/bgewehr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-08-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgewehr](https://answers.ros.org/users/23670/bgewehr/) on 2015-08-27**:
Now i found

```
 export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

to solve that. Where would you put that line in?

But now i get

```
ROS master URI is not set
```

and will go on searching...

**Comment by [bgewehr](https://answers.ros.org/users/23670/bgewehr/) on 2015-08-27**:
found out that export can do all that from the commandline - but is that really the way to do it? No config file or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Problem is the use of sudo. try ist with without  if you need the root rithgts then try dis

sudo su
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
./roscore

or

source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
sudo -E  ./roscore

Greet Anton

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1